# Making a get request in directive - Ionic Framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, httprequest, ionic-framework

I'm trying to adapt the angular-pickdate (https://github.com/jimibi/angular-pickadate) module to fit my needs, and I've reached a standstill, due to the impossibility of making a GET request the way I'm used to.

My code is :
...

```
.directive('pickadate', ['$locale', 'pickadateUtils', 'pickadateI18n', 'dateFilter', function($locale, dateUtils, i18n, dateFilter) {


  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      date: '=ngModel',
      defaultDate: '=',
      minDate: '=',
      maxDate: '=',
      disabledDates: '='
    },
    template:
      ...,

    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel,$http)  {

      var minDate       = scope.minDate && dateUtils.stringToDate(scope.minDate),
          maxDate       = scope.maxDate && dateUtils.stringToDate(scope.maxDate),
          disabledDates = scope.disabledDates || [],
          currentDate   = (scope.defaultDate && dateUtils.stringToDate(scope.defaultDate)) || new Date();

      scope.dayNames    = $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS['SHORTDAY'];
      scope.currentDate = currentDate;
      scope.t           = i18n.t;
      scope.render = function(initialDate,$http) {
        initialDate = new Date(initialDate.getFullYear(), initialDate.getMonth(), 1, 3);

          $http({url: 'myplace/script_lotacoes.php', method: 'GET'}).success(function(){alert("hheheh");}).error(function(){alert("oops");});
```

...

the error that this code gives me is :

```
  TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Scope.angular.module.provider.factory.directive.link.scope.render (angular-pickadate.js:122)
at angular.module.provider.factory.directive.link.ngModel.$render (angular-pickadate.js:191)
at Object.ngModelWatch (ionic.bundle.js:31576)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:22518)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:22789)
at done (ionic.bundle.js:17942)
at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:18132)
at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (ionic.bundle.js:18073)
```

This error is related to the $http request.

Does anyone have a clue why I get this error, and how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `$http.get('myplace/script_lotacoes.php').then(function() { alert('hheheh'); });`

Comment: I did. It gave me the following error:
    ypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at Scope.angular.module.provider.factory.directive.link.scope.render (angular-pickadate.js:123)...

Comment: Also try injecting `$http` into your directive definition, not the `link` function

Comment: Done that too lol Same error... it's weird.

Comment: did you then remove the `http` injection from `link()`?

Comment: remove it from `scope.render = function(initialDate,$http)` as well. You only need to inject this at the directive level

Comment: I injected it on the wrong place, you were right! Thanks!

Comment: Great to hear, please remember to accept my answer if you feel satisfied with the suggestion :)

Comment: Yes, I will do that. I just have to wait two more minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are injecting `$http` into your `link`function and well as your `scope.render` function. Remove these two injection attempts- you'll only need to inject this into your directive.

```
.directive('pickadate', ['$locale', 'pickadateUtils', 'pickadateI18n', 'dateFilter', '$http', function($locale, dateUtils, i18n, dateFilter, $http) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject the `$http` service in the directive:

```
.directive('pickadate', ['$http', '$locale', 'pickadateUtils', 'pickadateI18n', 'dateFilter', function($http, $locale, dateUtils, i18n, dateFilter) {
```